# Link multiple auth providers on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Currently I allow users to "Sign In with Facebook":

```
@objc func handleFBLogin() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }

        self.handleFBAccessToken()
    }
}

func handleFBAccessToken() {
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }
    let credentials = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {

        // I assume I handle the errors here

            print(error as Any)
            return
    }

        // successfully logged in user
        self.instantiateTabVC()
    }

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to add it so that if they've already made an account via email/password, the two accounts will be automatically linked/merged (or vice versa). In "I assume I handle the errors here", I added

```
let providers = Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: AuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey)   
// sign in with existing account 
// call linkWithCredential:completion:
```

to fetch the email that already exists. I am basing this off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583583/what-password-will-i-ask-if-auth-account-exists-with-different-credential-is-thr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345277/how-to-correctly-link-different-auth-accounts-in-firebase-ios?rq=1) (both similar questions). I understand that the premise is to

> use `fetchProvidersForEmail` with that email which will lookup the provider IDs associated with that email. You then sign in the user with one of those providers. After you finish sign-in with the existing account, you call linkWithCredential:completion: with the original credential that caused the error to occur

However, I am new to Swift and extremely confused about how to go about that. Any sample code would be extremely beneficial. I've also tried reading the documentation but that hasn't helped either (as I probably have not learned to properly understand the documentation)

I hope that I am moving in the right direction to solve this problem, however, if you have any other suggestions, I'd be open to that. I appreciate any help

Comment: seriously this question deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Approach this will doesn't create a new user if exists.

```
func facebook() {
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self, handler: { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if result!.isCancelled {
            print("FBLogin cancelled")
        } else {
            // [START headless_facebook_auth]
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            // [END headless_facebook_auth]
            self.firebaseLogin(credential)
        }
    })
}

func firebaseLogin(_ credential: AuthCredential) {

    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        // [START link_credential]
        user.link(with: credential) { _, error in
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if let error = error {
                self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        // [END link_credential]
    } else {
        // [START signin_credential]
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { _, error in
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            self.hideSpinner {
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                if let error = error {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    return
                }
                // User is signed in
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // Merge prevUser and currentUser accounts and data
                // ...
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
        // [END signin_credential]
    }

}
```

Comment: The whole block of code inside `if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser` doesn't run because `user` returns nil and then `signIn` fails because an account already exists. I believe the user needs to be signed in with the existing account before merge can occur

Comment: Yes, that happened